# How do I echo text in capital letters?

Tags: php, text, echo, capitalize

I want to know how to capitalize in PHP

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
echo strtoupper('hello');
```

[strtoupper](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) will capitalize the whole string.

If you're only interested in capitalizing the first letter, you can use [ucfirst](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ucfirst.php):

```
echo ucfirst('hello!'); //Hello!
```

If you want to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string, use [ucwords](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php):

```
echo ucwords('hello world!'); //Hello World!
```

Comment: @jason - Yep, that makes the answer more complete. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The [`strtoupper()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtoupper.php) function is what you're looking for.