# Echo text in capital letter using $row[$variable]

Tags: php

How to echo text in capital letter using `' . $row['variable_output'] . '` this my code. I already read and using this [How do I echo text in capital letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054631/how-do-i-echo-text-in-capital-letters) but didn't work.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and the results as it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want

```
echo strtoupper($row['variable_output']);
```

or if it is a string concatenation:

```
echo 'some text here: '. strtoupper($row['variable_output']) .' more text here';
```

Comment: Isn't that what the link in the question is saying to do, which they say *didn't work*

Comment: @NigelRen to me and you yes. But apparently the users struggles to realize how to get the "string" from the variable which he needs to pass to the function to concatenate to get the desired output. The provided link assumes you know how to do that.

Comment: @Haqem nice! happy coding

Comment: So it is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054631/how-do-i-echo-text-in-capital-letters